# Does Wi-Fi calling bypass your VPN?

Tags: iphone, vpn, wifi-calling

I have an iPhone 12 on iOS 17.2.1

1). Wi-Fi calling is enabled.

2). Proton VPN is installed, and enabled.

Is the Wi-Fi calling bypassing the VPN tunnel?

I know that on an Android phone, Wi-Fi calling is designed to bypass your VPN tunnel, connecting directly to the internet from your home router.

My understanding is that this was implemented as a concession to the telecom companies, to prevent people from using Wi-Fi calling to circumvent roaming charges when travelling overseas.

Is this also true on iPhones? Does Wi-Fi calling bypass the VPN?

I already suspect that it does, but I just wanted to be completely certain.

Comment: The trick, of course, when abroad & able to use local WiFi, is to Skype/Facetime whenever possible ;) My folks lived on another continent for 30 years. When we got everybody iPhones a decade or so ago our phone bills dropped by hundreds. Paid for the phones in months.